# scraping list of names from myanimelist user page

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, python-requests, lxml

I'm trying to make a list of all the names on this page https://myanimelist.net/users.php?lucky=1
though I can't figure out what path I need to use become right now I am just getting
['\n            ', '\n            ', '\n            ', etc.] instead of a list of usernames.

```
from lxml import html
import requests

link = 'https://myanimelist.net/users.php?lucky=1'
page = requests.get(link)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
names = tree.xpath('//td[@align="center"]/text()')
print(names)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

link = 'https://myanimelist.net/users.php?lucky=1'
page = requests.get(link)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
names = tree.xpath('//td[@align="center"]/div/a/text()')
print(names)
```

Comment: thanks! I'm new to anything with html so I wasn't sure how the commands worked